# What content do I need to install to get offline help for XNA in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

Using the Help Library Manager I have installed some help content for offline viewing, but when I click F1 on XNA objects, it tells me that I don't have help for that installed locally.  I've chosen to "Add" all the ones that I thought I would need, which is the one that contains the XNA help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the XNA 4.0 help is not available via that channel yet, you need to use the .chm file instead.

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/62406/383829.aspx